# gazebo_ros_package and error libaria2v5_2.8.0+repack-1ubuntu2_amd64 is not installed when compile catkin_ws

Tags: mythbuntu

Excuse me!

I have just installed `gazebo_ros_pkgs`, then i compiled `Catkin_workspace` with `catkin_make` it's take a error:
`libaria2v5_2.8.0+repack-1ubuntu2_amd64 is not installed.`

On the top bar now has a little red circle with a minus sign in it. when i click it, it opens a box with message in it:

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click from the right click window or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. 
The error message was:'Error: BrokenCount >0'. 
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

I'm used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial) and Ros Kinetic. My computer run dual boot ubuntu and win 10 home.

Hope you help me!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So, i have fixed that error by the following code:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libaria2v5_2.8.0+repack-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score -1):

So, i have just had a idea to solve a error which is  " `catkin_ws` is not compiled with `catkin_make`". ros_control is not included in `gazebo_ros_pkgs` is a reason for that.

That's insteresting when you try `git clone  https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control.git`.